# Проблема с редиректом в .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Есть такой htaccess (wordpress):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Нужно правило при котором, если в url имеется такой кусок "/new-posts/", то нужно редиректить на определенную страницу, причем чтобы url не менялся.

Например, url по которому переходит пользователь example.ru/new-posts/lala должен перенаправлять на страницу example.ru/custom, но чтобы в url остался изначальный адрес - example.ru/new-posts/lala . Пока добился только перенаправления, но со сменой url. Возможно ли вообще такое?

Comment: Невозможно в принципе. Одна из главных функций безопасности браузера - защита от подмены url.

Answer (score -1):

> Возможно ли вообще такое?

Нет, url уникальный единообразный локатор