# Как настроить редирект на другую страницу, но с тем же адресом в url в .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, apache

Есть такой htaccess (wordpress):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Нужно правило при котором, если в url имеется такой кусок "/new-posts/", то нужно открыть на определенную страницу, причем чтобы url не менялся.

Например, url по которому переходит пользователь example.ru/new-posts/lala должен открывать страницу example.ru/custom, но чтобы в url остался изначальный адрес - example.ru/new-posts/lala .

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с редиректом в .htaccess](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/885247/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-htaccess)

Comment: Не надо плодить вопросы. Это запрещено правилами.